# How can I add headers to my request in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, request-headers

Is it possible to add some headers, before sending a request to `GET` action ?
What I want to do, is to specify headers like:

```
-Accept application/json

-Content-Type application/json
```

...
before entering a `GET` method in my controller.

Comment: What do you use to send the request HttpClient, WebClient? Please, provide some code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx) sending a GET request with Accept and Content-Type headers would look something like this:

```
        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, requestUri)
        {
            Content = content,
        };
        request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        request.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);
```

Keep in mind that the code uses the Async version of sending the request, so you have to decorate your method with the "Async" keyword in order for this to work.

If you want to send the request from the front-end you should use ajax and your code would look something like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'URL HERE',
  type: 'GET',
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function (data) {
    // here goes the data that came from the response..
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

How about this?

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("GetData", "Home")',
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (result) {
    }
});
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult GetData()  
{
   return Json("What I want to send", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```